# How to open a filepath given by fnamemodify() in Vimscript

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make a function to open a specified Project Euler problem. Here's what I have:

```
function ProjectEuler ()
    let problem = input('Enter problem number: ')
    cd /Users/me/Documents/Computer_Stuff/Code/Project_Euler
    e fnamemodify('problem'.problem.'.py', ':p') 
endfunction
```

fnamemodify() gives the correct filepath to any problem I enter, so my thinking was that `e` would then open the file at that filepath, but instead it opens `/Users/me/Documents/Computer_Stuff/Code/Project_Euler/fnamemodify('problem'.problem.'.py', ':p')`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `:execute` to use variables or expressions in a mapping or command.

```
execute "edit " . fnamemodify('foo.txt', ':p')
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now. What's the difference between `e` and things like `echo` in this context? Seeing as the latter works fine.

Comment: `e` is short for `edit` (you should use the longform, BTW), it accepts a filename as argument but not expressions. `echo` is not as picky.

Comment: Tiny bit simpler: `execute "edit" fnamemodify('foo.txt', ':p')`.

Comment: @romainl, does "Oooooh" mean you are impressed with my detailed knowledge of `:execute` or that you think I goofed?

Comment: I'm impressed. I never even think about doing that. Thanks.